# ContextMenu based on enum in bound object

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, enums, triggers

My `Node` class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace FrontEnd
{
    public enum NodeType
    {
        SQLite,
        Database,
        TableCollection,
        ViewCollection,
        IndexCollection,
        TriggerCollection,
        ColumnCollection,
        Table,
        View,
        Column,
        Index,
        Trigger
    }

    public class Node
    {
        public string Title { get; protected set; }
        public NodeType Type { get; protected set; }
        public ObservableCollection<Node> Nodes { get; set; }

        public Node(string title, NodeType type)
        {
            this.Title = title;
            this.Type = type;
            this.Nodes = new ObservableCollection<Node>();
        }
    }
}
```

My XAML:

```
    <TreeView Name="dbTree" Padding="0,5,0,0">
        <TreeView.Resources>
            <ContextMenu x:Key="ScaleCollectionPopup">
                <MenuItem Header="New Scale..."/>
            </ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu x:Key="ScaleItemPopup">
                <MenuItem Header="Remove Scale"/>
            </ContextMenu>
        </TreeView.Resources>
        <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Type, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="NodeType.Column">
                        <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource ScaleItemPopup}" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Nodes}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,4">
                    <Image Source="{Binding Converter={StaticResource StringToImageConverter}}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" Padding="5,0,0,0" />
                </StackPanel>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    </TreeView>
```

What I am trying to achieve and failing is to decide on the `ContextMenu` to use based on the `Type` property of the bound `Node` classes.

If its a Table or View I would like to display "SELECT 1000 ROWS" & "SHOW CREATE SQL", for other types I want to define other options.

What is the correct way to achieve the desired effect?

Comment: data templates & data triggers can help you switch the menu as desired

Comment: @pushpraj As you see that is my approach above, but it does not work, I was hoping someone could shed light on my mistakes.

Comment: what is the ItemsSource of Treeview? also try `<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Type}" Value="Column">`. perhaps check any data binding error you see in output window. also you may try to move the resources as style resources if needed.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to do it in mvvm style when the context menu is generated by view model of each node. See the example below:

View part:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:wpfApplication1="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
    d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance wpfApplication1:ViewModel}">
<Grid>
    <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Nodes}">
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Nodes}">
                <StackPanel>
                    <StackPanel.ContextMenu>
                        <ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding ContextMenu}">
                            <ContextMenu.Resources>
                                <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
                                    <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Command}"/>
                                </Style>
                            </ContextMenu.Resources>
                            <ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>
                                <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"/>
                                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                            </ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>
                        </ContextMenu>
                    </StackPanel.ContextMenu>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    </TreeView>
</Grid>
```

And view model part:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new ViewModel();
    }
}

public class MenuItem
{
    public MenuItem()
    {
        Items = new ObservableCollection<MenuItem>();
    }

    public string Title { get; set; }
    public ICommand Command { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<MenuItem> Items { get; private set; }
}

public class ViewModel
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
        Nodes = new ObservableCollection<Node>
        {
            new Node("MSSQL", NodeType.Database,
                new Node("Customers", NodeType.Table)),
            new Node("Oracle", NodeType.Database)
        }; 
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Node> Nodes { get; set; }
}

public enum NodeType
{
    Database,
    Table,
}

public class Node
{
    public string Title { get; protected set; }
    public NodeType Type { get; protected set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Node> Nodes { get; set; }

    public Node(string title, NodeType type, params Node[] nodes)
    {
        this.Title = title;
        this.Type = type;
        this.Nodes = new ObservableCollection<Node>();
        if (nodes != null)
            nodes.ToList().ForEach(this.Nodes.Add);
    }

    public IEnumerable<MenuItem> ContextMenu
    {
        get { return createMenu(this); }
    }

    private static IEnumerable<MenuItem> createMenu(Node node)
    {
        switch (node.Type)
        {
            case NodeType.Database:
                return new List<MenuItem>
                {
                    new MenuItem {Title = "Create table...",  Command = new RelayCommand(o => MessageBox.Show("Table created"))}
                };
            case NodeType.Table:
                return new List<MenuItem>
                {
                    new MenuItem {Title = "Select..."},
                    new MenuItem {Title = "Edit..."}
                };
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }
}

public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    #region Fields

    readonly Action<object> _execute;
    readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;

    #endregion // Fields

    #region Constructors

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute)
        : this(execute, null)
    {
    }

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
    {
        if (execute == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");

        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }
    #endregion // Constructors

    #region ICommand Members

    [DebuggerStepThrough]
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canExecute == null || _canExecute(parameter);
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _execute(parameter);
    }

    #endregion // ICommand Members
}
```

(you can use any implementation ICommand interface, RelayCommand is one of them)
You can generate menu items in the Node class or in an IContextMenuBuilder service that can be passed into the Node constructor.

Comment: nice example, keep it up, happy coding :)